# Primes modulo which a given quadratic equation has roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a quadratic polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$, with $a$, $b$ and $c$ being integers, is there a characterization of all primes $p$ for which the equation
$$ax^2 + bx + c \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
has solutions?

I have seen it [mentioned](http://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/frobreso.pdf) that it follows from quadratic reciprocity that the set is precisely the primes in some arithmetic progression, but the statement may require some tweaking. The set of primes modulo which $1 + \lambda = \lambda^2$ has solutions seems to be $$5, 11, 19, 29, 31, 41, 59, 61, 71, 79, 89, 101, 109, 131, 139, 149, 151, 179, 181, 191, 199, \dots$$ which are ($5$ and) the primes that are $1$ or $9$ modulo $10$.

(Can the question also be answered for equations of higher degree?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All but finitely many of the primes can be characterized by quadratic reciprocity. First handle the primes $p$ dividing $a$ (there is a solution if and only if $c \equiv 0 \bmod p$ or $b \not \equiv 0 \bmod p$). Next handle $p = 2$ (using the fact that $x^2 \equiv x \bmod 2$, so there is a solution if and only if $c$ is even or $a + b$ is odd).

For all remaining primes, complete the square to obtain
$$\left( 2ax + b \right)^2 = b^2 - 4ac.$$

It follows that a solution exists if and only if $\left( \frac{b^2 - 4ac}{p} \right) = 1$, and the conditions for this to occur are given by quadratic reciprocity. (You get a congruence condition, but you also need to take into account all the primes dividing $b^2 - 4ac$.)

---

The situation for polynomials of higher degree is considerably more complicated (and I'll warn you in advance that I'm far from an expert in these matters, so take everything I say with a grain of salt). First, reduce WLOG to the irreducible case. If the Galois group of the polynomial is abelian, then by [Kronecker-Weber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%E2%80%93Weber_theorem) the polynomial splits over some cyclotomic extension, so the way the polynomial factors modulo a prime is determined (again up to finitely many exceptions) by congruence conditions; this is all a part of the edifice of [class field theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_field_theory). I have been told that [Artin reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin_reciprocity) provides the appropriate generalization of quadratic reciprocity here but I don't know the details.

If the Galois group of the polynomial is non-abelian then the primes are **not** determined by congruence conditions. One can say some things about their statistical distribution using [Chebotarev's density theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem) but to actually characterize them is the subject of ongoing research and a part of what the [Langlands program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langlands_program) is supposed to do. At [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11747/galoisian-sets-of-prime-numbers) an example is given relating a specific modular form to roots modulo primes of the polynomial $x^3 - x - 1$ (or maybe the minimal polynomial of a primitive element of its splitting field instead).

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on [the conditions for $\left( \frac{b^2 - 4ac}{p} \right) = 1$ are given by quadratic reciprocity]? Assuming $p$ does not divide $b^2 - 4ac$, how is it a congruence condition?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: factor $b^2 - 4ac$ into the greatest power of $2$ dividing it and its odd part. Use quadratic reciprocity on the first factor and Jacobi reciprocity on the second. You'll conclude that $\left( \frac{b^2 - 4ac}{p} \right)$ is a periodic function of $p$ with period something like $4p$.

Answer (score 4):

I never noticed this one before.

$$  x^3 - x - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p  $$
has one root for odd primes $p$ with $(-23|p) = -1.$

$$  x^3 - x - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p  $$
has three distinct roots for odd $p$ with $(-23|p) = 1$ and $p = u^2 + 23 v^2 $ in integers.

$$  x^3 - x - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p  $$
has no roots for odd $p$ with $(-23|p) = 1$ and $p = 3u^2 + 2 u v + 8 v^2 $ in integers (not necessarily positive integers).

Here we go, no roots $\pmod 2,$ but a doubled root and a single $\pmod {23},$ as
$$  x^3 - x - 1 \equiv (x - 3)(x-10)^2 \pmod {23}. $$

Strange but true. Easy to confirm by computer for primes up to 1000, say.

The example you can see completely proved in books, Ireland and Rosen for example, is $x^3 - 2,$ often with the phrase "the cubic character of 2" and the topic "cubic reciprocity." $2$ is a cube for primes $p=2,3$ and any prime $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3.$ Also, $2$ is a cube for primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $p = x^2 + 27 y^2$ in integers. However, $2$ is not a cube for primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $p = 4x^2 +2 x y + 7 y^2$ in integers. (Gauss)

$3$ is a cube for primes $p=2,3$ and any prime $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3.$ Also, $3$ is a cube for primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $p = x^2 + x y + 61 y^2$ in integers. However, $3$ is not a cube for primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $p = 7x^2 +3 x y + 9 y^2$ in integers. (Jacobi)

Comment: Nice example, thank you.